# Injecting HIbernate session into Welblogic 10.3.6 EJB2

Tags: cdi, weblogic11g

Can someone please provide the example of injecting hebiernate session into ejb 2 deployed on Weblogic 10.3.6 either with WELD or OpenWebBeans ?

Is it supported at all ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify? Hibernate works like any other JPA provider on WebLogic, you can inject it using `@PersistenceContext`

Comment: I'll try the JPA way, but what about pure Hibernate session factory or any other resourse? I saw many examples how to enable OWB and Weld (which doesn't support WL 10.3.6 container) using session listener at war level, but how to enable it for ejb 2 module ?

Comment: Well, considering that you can't inject into EJB 2, I'm really not sure what you're after.

Comment: I was after CDI into EJB 2, just needed a confirmation that it's not feasible. Thanks